# Linking update action to the close button of jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I would like to link an event to the jquery dialog closing button.
    I'll do my best to describe the situation:
    I have a kind of agenda with 5 days (monday to friday) each day can have 20 rows.
    When you click on a rox of a specific day, a jquery dialog appears which contains an iFrame (linking to agenda_lestijd.aspx)
    where the user can put data and save it by means of a button in the page (agenda_lestijd.aspx).
    When I close the jQuery dialog I like to launch the event of btnUpdate which means that only the row op the specific day will be updated and not whole the page.
    At this moment I put the btnUpdate button on the page and it works perfectly ....but I hope that there is a way to use the close-button of the jquery dialog box.

```
HTML code + jquery:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a#pop').live('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var page = $(this).attr("href")
var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
.dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
height: 800,
width: 1200,
title: pagetitle,
close: ReloadPage,
position: ["center", 20]
});
$dialog.dialog('open');
});
});
function ReloadPage() {
alert('test');
}
</script>

this is one of the updatepanels:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<tr>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" onClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text ="Update" />
<asp:Label ID="labWeekOverzichtLestijd1_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="labWeekOverzichtLestijd2_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="labWeekOverzichtLestijd3_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="labWeekOverzichtLestijd4_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="labWeekOverzichtLestijd5_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</tr>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

I fill the agenda with a function in the codebehind:

For i = 1 To 20
fillLestijd (lestijd_index:=i, lestijden:=lestijden)
Next

Private Sub fillLestijd(ByVal lestijd_index As Integer, ByVal lestijden As Array) //here is also the link for activating the jquery dialog
labWeekOverzichtLestijd = "<td class='" + Session("dagkleur") + "'><span class='" + titelkleur + "'><a id='pop' href='agenda_lestijd.aspx?" & Session("weeknummer") & "&datum=" & datum & "&lestijd=" & var & "' title='Lestijden'><img src= 'graphics/edit1.png'></a>"
end sub

This is the code for the update of just one row:
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
fillLestijd(lestijd_index:=aantal, lestijden:=lestijden)
Select Case aantal
Case 1
UpdatePanel1.Update()
Case 2
UpdatePanel2.Update()
Case 3
UpdatePanel3.Update()
Case 4
UpdatePanel4.Update()
Case 5
UpdatePanel5.Update()
Case 6
UpdatePanel6.Update()
Case 7
UpdatePanel7.Update()
Case 8
UpdatePanel8.Update()
Case 9
UpdatePanel9.Update()
Case 10
UpdatePanel10.Update()
Case 11
UpdatePanel11.Update()
Case 12
UpdatePanel12.Update()
Case 13
UpdatePanel13.Update()
Case 14
UpdatePanel14.Update()
Case 15
UpdatePanel15.Update()
Case 16
UpdatePanel16.Update()
Case 17
UpdatePanel17.Update()
Case 18
UpdatePanel18.Update()
Case 19
UpdatePanel19.Update()
Case 20
UpdatePanel20.Update()
End Select
End Sub

Can I get help for this topic?? Thxs
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $( ".selector" ).dialog({
      beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
// do whatever you want before dialog closes
}
    });
```

for more info, check [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose)

Hope this helps.